# Move files within s3 folders based on job status

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, workflow, aws-glue

I have an `ETL` job that loads data from `S3` to `Redshift.`

My s3 bucket should have 3 folders named A,B and C where files will be uploaded to A and when job is running then the files should be transferred to B and if job run succeed then files should transferred from B to C.I have already enabled `job bookmark`.

I discovered that workflow in AWS `Glue` will help me out for doing this where maybe I create a Lambda function with a `conditional trigger` python script and use `EventBridge.` However, as I am using `transformation_ctx`, how I could find out that files should not get duplicated means only those files should be transformed which are currently used by job not all I mean how I use the bookmark so the above mentioned criteria is being satisfied.